# AttributeError: 'zipimport.zipimporter' object has no attribute 'exec_module'

Tags: python, spyder

Bien, estoy intentando configurar una API de binance. Me descargué Python 3.9 y Spyder.

Instalé `python-binance` tal y como dicta la documentación, a través del cmd escribí `pip install python-binance`, y perfecto, tengo ya binance en ../site-packages/

Copié las librerías necesarias de Python39 a ../Spyder/pkgs y todo correcto (ya que no me dejaba instalarlo via comando en el propio Spyder, tuve que hacerlo manual con un copypaste)

Ahora me da el siguente error:

Ejecutando esta línea: `from binance.client import Client`

Me salta esto:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Aaron/Desktop/Documentos/programming/.py/apiq.py', wdir='C:/Users/Aaron/Desktop/Documentos/programming/.py')
Reloaded modules: jupyter_client.session, zmq.eventloop, zmq.eventloop.ioloop, tornado.platform, tornado.platform.asyncio, tornado.gen, zmq.eventloop.zmqstream, jupyter_client.jsonutil, jupyter_client.adapter, binance, requests, urllib3, urllib3.exceptions, urllib3._version, urllib3.connectionpool, urllib3.connection, urllib3.packages, urllib3.packages.ssl_match_hostname, urllib3.packages.six, urllib3.util, urllib3.util.connection, urllib3.contrib, urllib3.contrib._appengine_environ, urllib3.util.wait, urllib3.util.request, urllib3.util.response, urllib3.util.retry, urllib3.util.ssl_, urllib3.util.url, urllib3.util.ssltransport, urllib3.util.timeout, urllib3.util.proxy, urllib3._collections, urllib3.request, urllib3.filepost, urllib3.fields, urllib3.response, urllib3.util.queue, urllib3.poolmanager, chardet, chardet.universaldetector, chardet.charsetgroupprober, chardet.enums, chardet.charsetprober, chardet.escprober, chardet.codingstatemachine, chardet.escsm, chardet.latin1prober, chardet.mbcsgroupprober, chardet.utf8prober, chardet.mbcssm, chardet.sjisprober, chardet.mbcharsetprober, chardet.chardistribution, chardet.euctwfreq, chardet.euckrfreq, chardet.gb2312freq, chardet.big5freq, chardet.jisfreq, chardet.jpcntx, chardet.eucjpprober, chardet.gb2312prober, chardet.euckrprober, chardet.cp949prober, chardet.big5prober, chardet.euctwprober, chardet.sbcsgroupprober, chardet.hebrewprober, chardet.langbulgarianmodel, chardet.sbcharsetprober, chardet.langgreekmodel, chardet.langhebrewmodel, chardet.langrussianmodel, chardet.langthaimodel, chardet.langturkishmodel, chardet.version, requests.exceptions, requests.__version__, requests.utils, requests.certs, certifi, certifi.core, requests._internal_utils, requests.compat, requests.cookies, requests.structures, requests.packages, requests.packages.urllib3, requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions, requests.packages.urllib3._version, requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool, requests.packages.urllib3.connection, requests.packages.urllib3.packages, requests.packages.urllib3.packages.ssl_match_hostname, requests.packages.urllib3.packages.six, requests.packages.urllib3.util, requests.packages.urllib3.util.connection, requests.packages.urllib3.contrib, requests.packages.urllib3.contrib._appengine_environ, requests.packages.urllib3.util.wait, requests.packages.urllib3.util.request, requests.packages.urllib3.util.response, requests.packages.urllib3.util.retry, requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_, requests.packages.urllib3.util.url, requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssltransport, requests.packages.urllib3.util.timeout, requests.packages.urllib3.util.proxy, requests.packages.urllib3._collections, requests.packages.urllib3.request, requests.packages.urllib3.filepost, requests.packages.urllib3.fields, requests.packages.urllib3.response, requests.packages.urllib3.util.queue, requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager, idna, idna.package_data, idna.core, idna.idnadata, idna.intranges, requests.packages.idna, requests.packages.idna.package_data, requests.packages.idna.core, requests.packages.idna.idnadata, requests.packages.idna.intranges, requests.packages.chardet, requests.packages.chardet.universaldetector, requests.packages.chardet.charsetgroupprober, requests.packages.chardet.enums, requests.packages.chardet.charsetprober, requests.packages.chardet.escprober, requests.packages.chardet.codingstatemachine, requests.packages.chardet.escsm, requests.packages.chardet.latin1prober, requests.packages.chardet.mbcsgroupprober, requests.packages.chardet.utf8prober, requests.packages.chardet.mbcssm, requests.packages.chardet.sjisprober, requests.packages.chardet.mbcharsetprober, requests.packages.chardet.chardistribution, requests.packages.chardet.euctwfreq, requests.packages.chardet.euckrfreq, requests.packages.chardet.gb2312freq, requests.packages.chardet.big5freq, requests.packages.chardet.jisfreq, requests.packages.chardet.jpcntx, requests.packages.chardet.eucjpprober, requests.packages.chardet.gb2312prober, requests.packages.chardet.euckrprober, requests.packages.chardet.cp949prober, requests.packages.chardet.big5prober, requests.packages.chardet.euctwprober, requests.packages.chardet.sbcsgroupprober, requests.packages.chardet.hebrewprober, requests.packages.chardet.langbulgarianmodel, requests.packages.chardet.sbcharsetprober, requests.packages.chardet.langgreekmodel, requests.packages.chardet.langhebrewmodel, requests.packages.chardet.langrussianmodel, requests.packages.chardet.langthaimodel, requests.packages.chardet.langturkishmodel, requests.packages.chardet.version, requests.models, requests.hooks, requests.auth, requests.status_codes, requests.api, requests.sessions, requests.adapters, regex, regex.regex, regex._regex_core, regex._regex, spyder, spyder.pil_patch, PIL, PIL._version, PIL.Image, PIL.ImageMode, PIL.TiffTags, PIL._binary, PIL._util, PIL._imaging, cffi, cffi.api, cffi.lock, cffi.error, cffi.model
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Aaron\Desktop\Documentos\programming\.py\apiq.py", line 8, in <module>
    from binance.client import Client

  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\binance\client.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .helpers import date_to_milliseconds, interval_to_milliseconds

  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\binance\helpers.py", line 3, in <module>
    import dateparser

  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\dateparser\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .date import DateDataParser

  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\dateparser\date.py", line 9, in <module>
    from dateparser.date_parser import date_parser

  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\dateparser\date_parser.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .conf import apply_settings

  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\dateparser\conf.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .parser import date_order_chart

  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\dateparser\parser.py", line 12, in <module>
    from dateparser.utils.strptime import strptime

  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\dateparser\utils\strptime.py", line 57, in <module>
    __strptime = patch_strptime()

  File "C:\Users\Aaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Spyder\pkgs\dateparser\utils\strptime.py", line 28, in patch_strptime
    _strptime_spec.loader.exec_module(_strptime)

AttributeError: 'zipimport.zipimporter' object has no attribute 'exec_module'
```

¿Qué puedo hacer con el tema del AttributeError? Si ejecuto el .py directamente, en el cmd sale toda la información que necesito, pero después se cierra, el problema de Spyder (y lo mismo pasaba con PyCharm)

Comment: Cuando dices que copiastes _"las librerías necesarias de Python39 a ../Spyder/pkgs"_, ¿podrías específicar qué librerías fueron? El error tiene pintas de que estás usando alguna librería antigua que usa el anterior importador de módulos.

Comment: si, fueron: binance, dateparser, dateparser_data, dateparser_scripts y dateparser_1.0.0.dist-info
Creo que no me dejo ninguna mas. Pero toda librería que me pedía al decir "no module name X" la copiaba y pegaba de Python

Comment: El módulo `dateparser.utils.strptime` tiene pintas de ser un _módulo virtual_ que se configura al vuelo. Spyder no lo sabe encontrar (_dateparser_ no se inicializa correctamente dentro de spyder). La mejor recomendación que te puedo dar es que intentes que Spyder use el entorno python donde has instalado `dateparser`. Aún mejor, usa entornos virtuales.

Comment: Any progress? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: Si @RosenSofroniev, luego en casa te paso docu que tengo